# How to select elements without any text with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm testing a search page, where user filters records by value. Long story short - I need to check the number of elements without any text in their node (I'm reseting the filter and checking if the elements without any text appear).

How do I select all elements without any text?

I'm using this, but it returns all the elements anyway:

```
expect(page.all('table.index tbody td.status', text: '').count).to be == 0
```

Comment: did you try `page.all('table.index tbody td.status').select{|field| field.val == '' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :text option takes a string or a regex.  When it's a string it does substring matching so `''` will match all the elements.  What you want is

```
expect(page).to have_no_css('table.index tbody td.status', text: /^$/)
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_css('table.index tbody td.status', text: /^$/, count: 0)
```

99.9% of the time you're better off using the provided matchers (have_css, have_selector, etc.), rather than calling count on the results of `all`, because you'll get Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior on the expectation